# Set dictionary values in Python while subtracting from a max allowed total value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do something simple in Python. I'm a little rusty so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I want to give random values to dictionary items. Each loop I want to subtract from the original value so if a house has 5 rooms then the total doesn't ever go over 5 for the combined items in the dictionary.

This is not homework. I work IT and I'm trying to practice my Python which is one of my weaker known scripting languages.

Simplified in the terminal it appears to work but when I put it in the code I get an error.

Terminal:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.8 (default, Apr 25 2019, 21:02:35) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import random
>>> h1 = random.randint(1,5)
>>> size = random.randint(1, h1)
>>> h1 = h1 - size
>>> print(h1)
2
```

Script:

```
import random
h1 = random.randint(1,5)

rooms = {
"bed" : 0,
"bath": 0,
"study": 0
}

for z in rooms:
  size = random.randint(1, h1)
  room_types[z] = size

  if h1_size != 0:
    h1 = h1 - size

for x, y in rooms.items():
  print(x, y)
```

I get the following error:

```
$ ./two.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./two.py", line 13, in <module>
    size = random.randint(1, h1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/random.py", line 221, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/random.py", line 199, in randrange
    raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,1, 0)
```

Comment: Looks like you are using `random.randint(a, b)` with `a > b` and this is not supported.

Comment: Your code fails to run due to an undefined variable.

Comment: `h1_size` is not defined. Did you mean `h1 - size`?

Comment: Also, to elaborate on @norok2's comment above. it looks like from the second loop iteration on, `h1` could be: `h1 <= 1`, which means, that you could be calling `randint()` with an empty or negative range. Please clarify in the question what you are trying to achieve and it will be easier to help.

Comment: Yes.. I changed h1_size to h1 for this post. Tried to simplify things as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the script you're re-assigning `h1` with `h1 - size` in each iteration of the `for` loop, and if `size` happens to be `h1` as it is the upper bound passed to `randint`, `h1` would become `0` after the assignment, so that in the next iteration you would be effectively calling `random.randint(1, 0)`, where the upper bound is less than the lower bound, which is disallowed and therefore produces the said error.

Comment: Thank you. I moved the "if h1 != 0" to right before setting the size which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider a simple example.  You randomly select a 4-room house.  Your random numbers give you 3 bedrooms and one bath.  Your loop continues to "study" and tries to generate a random number form 1 to 0.  You neglected to reserve a room for that requirement.  Python considers the inverted range to be an error.

If you truly require at least one room of each type, then allocate those before you choose random numbers, allowing a choice of 0 thereafter.  If you don't require at least one room, then reduce the lower bound of your `rangrange`.